# Inserting arrays of Object IDs in mgo

Tags: mongodb, data-structures, go, mgo

So recently I've been trying to insert different types of data into structures using mgo, and I've ran into a bit of a snag. When trying to insert an array of object IDs, I can't seem to figure out that format if I were to populate that object ID array within the structure.

Here's the structure as follows

```
type Group struct {
ID        bson.ObjectId     `json:"id" bson:"_id"`
GroupName string            `json:"groupName"`
UserIDs   []*bson.ObjectId      `json:"users" bson:"userid"`
Expected  []*int            `json:"expected"`
Actual    []*int            `json:"actual"`
}
```

And the operation I am trying to run is to insert a new "test" table with a single userID into UserIDs.

```
array := []*bson.ObjectId{&findJ.ID}

c = Session.DB("test").C("Group")
err = c.Insert(&Group{GroupName: "test", UserIDs: array})
ThisPanic(err)
```

Where findJ has it's own ID from a separate structure. What am I doing wrong here, as it is causing a panic on inserting the array.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the pointers! I will get the actual code output here shortly. I tried playing around with it before, but was still getting errors (on the array I had a different declaration), but I will get the output here soon!

Comment: Couldn't edit my comment, but here's the output of the error: `Cannot take the address of bson.objectId(findJ.ID)`

Comment: Also, another error that has been popping up is `ObjectIDs must be exactly 12 bytes long (got 0)`.

Comment: After removing all pointers, the aforementioned of a 0 byte ObjectID was passed. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: Sorry, I mean the error specifically is saying it's not passing the proper ID. As in, if I print findJ.ID before, it outputs the value `ObjectIdHex("5654df213610fec33e7eb342")
panic: ObjectIDs must be exactly 12 bytes long (got 0)
` and then the panic happens right after, when it is trying to insert into the group (and yes, I am switching collections to group itself too)